# Ubuntu LTS not booting on late 2009 IMac

Tags: boot, 18.04, mac, lts, usb-installation

I am new to the Linux scene and am having a problem booting my mac with Ubuntu LTS 18.04.2. I have a late 2009 iMac running macOS High Sierra and I can't get my Ubuntu USB to boot. I run into the same error when I choose the Boot on the selection screen. It will show the typical Ubuntu boot font with the black background and white text but it will say the following:

"Reloc 0 block size -1 greater than reloc dirsize 3584, which is invalid

Relocation failed: Unsupported

Failed to load image: Unsupported

Start_image() returned Unsupported"

Can I get some help understanding what this means and how to solve the problem? I thought my computer met the minimum specs for Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Comment: I would validate your install media (there should be an option on the install media to check your install media).  It takes a couple of minutes at most, but it can save hours of wasted diagnostics if either download, or write to media step was imperfect.

Comment: I'm using balenaEtcher right now and I think it validates after writing. I could have an imperfect download, I'll try redownloading and give that a shot.

Comment: Rather than re-download & re-write, when you boot it select 'check install media' at the menu (I don't know what you see on a mac, but it'll be either a menu of options, or a person-in-circle + keyboard-in-rectangle which will change to a menu if you press a key.  This option is what I'm selecting.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  (*it may still even call the usb a 'cd' though it'll look different to those images*)

Comment: After checking, it turns out I did have a bad download. I went ahead and reinstalled the ISO and rewrote to the USB. Worked fine when I rebooted! Thank you for the help!

Comment: I have too a late 2009 iMac, and just installed ubuntu 20.04 following https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview but at boot time, I followed https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/es-mx/000123893/opci%C3%B3n-manual-de-l%C3%ADnea-de-inicio-kernel-nomodeset-para-el-inicio-de-linux